# SAS Proc MI SAS output

Tags: sas, imputation

Proc MI is used to impute missing values in a SAS dataset. Is there a way to obtain a SAS code from Proc MI procedure, so that we can score datasets with missing value without having to use Proc MI procedure? This is needed so that dataset in production environment can be score consistently. I dont want to use Proc MI in production environment.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "scoring datasets"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, at least not in the way that it is for `proc import`. If you want to use a purely deterministic imputation algorithm, you will need to write your own data step to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how complicated your data set is, but if you score a data set that covers all the possibilities you will see in the production data, then you can use your scored data set as a lookup table for the production data.